# Beaglebone Black won't show-up as /dev/ttyUSB

Tags: arm, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am trying to learn Linux by following instructions in "Mastering Embedded Linux Programming" by Chris Simmonds. By following the book and with some help from [Stack_Overflow_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284222/u-boot-for-beaglebone-black-wont-build-target-cpu-does-not-support-thumb-inst), i was able to build the MLO and u-boot.img.

However, when i connect USB cable to my PC and execute the *ls /dev/tty** command, i cannot find any device with */dev/ttyUSB*. All i can see are devices with */dev/tty0-63*, */dev/ttyS0-31* and one /dev/ttyprintk.

Also, when i press down the S2 button and connect the USB cable, i can only see the power led glowing and nothing else.

I have properly built the u-boot (three attempts to get it right).

Also, as per the instructions in the book, i am only testing the u-boot stuff and yet to reach the kernal part.

If i remove the sd card and connect the USB, im an able to talk to my BBB over ssh (192.168.7.2).

How to i get the u-boot to work? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have one yet, I'd recommend to get a USB-to-serial device (3.3V Vref). You connect it to the debug UART (J1) which is located next to the P9 side. Nowadays those are very cheap and can cost below 1$. Ones that feature a genuine FTDI part will be 5-10$ at least.

The serial port you are referencing is only available once the device has passed through U-Boot, booted the kernel and finally userspace has set up the communications.

Especially when working with U-Boot and the Kernel, low level UART access is crucial.

As a further note, could it be that the Book refers to the (white) original Beaglebone? That has a FTDI USB-to-UART chip on board and will allow you even U-Boot access. You can do the same things if you have the above mentioned USB device.

Comment: The location of the debug UART is shown in https://github.com/beagleboard/beaglebone-black/wiki/System-Reference-Manual#43-board-component-locations

Comment: HI TBR, thanks a lot. Will try with the USB-to-serial device and post here.

Comment: Got it to work with the USB-to-serial device! Thanks a ton :-)

Comment: glad to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

https://groups.google.com/g/beagleboard/c/eNDjK05spY8/m/GPvhcP52BAAJ shows that one needs to hold the space key to enter u-boot.

Also, the info. here might be more up to date compared to the book.

- https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black

There is no way to copy and paste everything from the eewiki. I just left you the link. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi De Funct, thanks a lot for the answer. I will go through and keep posting.